# Can pumpkin/sunflower/flax/sesame/other seeds regulate hormones?

Tags: nutrition, biology, physiology, nutritional-supplements

My wife has started using a technique using various seeds through various times to regulate hormone balance. Does this have any merit?

[Here](http://naturalhealthperspectives.blogspot.ca/2012/02/seed-cycling-for-natural-hormonal.html)'s an example of using seeds as a supplement to regulate hormones:

> Rotating of seeds is a valuable way of restoring hormonal balance for men and women.   Seed cycling is so effective because the hulls of the seeds contain chemicals called lignans, which help modulate the hormonal pathways of the body while the seed oils are comprised of essential (or omega) fatty acids that provide the building blocks for steroid hormone synthesis.
>
> As each seed type contains variations of these lignans and fatty acids, rotation of these seeds through the month provides the body with the variety of precursors it needs to create normal hormonal cycles.  The additional oils (EPA/DHA & GLA) may also be added for added balancing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, indirectly.

Flaxseeds don't inherently regulate hormones on their own, but they do provide a rich source of Omega-3 fatty acids.

[Omega-3s help by](http://blog.betterinnovations.com/2011/06/30/supporting-hormonal-balance-with-omega-3):

> "Enabl[ing] the fats to create healthy, flexible and responsive cell
>   membranes that accommodates cells in a rather more convenient and easy
>   way.  While such is the primary health benefit of fish oil, omega-3
>   fatty acids likewise help in the body by **ensuring that the cellular
>   receptor sites are repaired, in good condition and will work in
>   optimal force** anytime."

Having [optimal cellular receptors, in turn, is necessary to regulate hormones](http://mend.endojournals.org/content/5/10/1405.short).

Ergo, seeds provide the body with Omega-3s which in turn help repair and optimize cellular receptors which in turn keep hormones balanced.